# How to get Facebook users language?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I've searched the Facebooks api, but I can't figure out how to get the users languages. For example, if a user enters 'French', 'German' as their languages in the Contact/Basic Info page, I'd like to know the api to get that information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the language from the API - "Facebook Pages representing the languages this person knows."

**"the 'user_likes' permission is used for fetching languages via Facebook API.**

**You can check this explanation here on how to obtain users language details here** https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

check here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/page

check the list of available info here from Facebook api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user

See this code for language info permission

```
{
        bio = "Love sports of all kinds.";
        birthday = "01/01/1980";
        "favorite_athletes" =             (
                            {
                id = 20242388857;
                name = "Usain Bolt";
            }
        );
        "first_name" = Chris;
        hometown =             {
            id = 106033362761104;
            name = "Campbell, California";
        };
        id = 100003086810435;
        languages =             (
                            {
                id = 108106272550772;
                name = French;
            },
                            {
                id = 312525296370;
                name = Spanish;
            }
        );
        "last_name" = Colm;
        link = "http://www.facebook.com/chris.colm";
        locale = "en_US";
        location =             {
            id = 104048449631599;
            name = "Menlo Park, California";
        };
        "middle_name" = Abe;
        name = "Chris Abe Colm";
        timezone = "-7";
        "updated_time" = "2012-08-09T03:33:32+0000";
        username = "chris.colm";
        verified = 1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but non of the permissions mention languages, and I'm not getting any results just by passing the languages parameter to the api. Is there something special to do with the 'Pages'

Comment: See this code for fetching user info (language too)

Comment: are you building a website or a phone app?

Comment: Android phone app actually, so Java Request objects!

Comment: then this link will be surly helpful https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph

Comment: Oh wow, it was the 'user_likes' permission. Hey, could you just put that in your answer so I can select it as the correct one?

Comment: Thank you, your original answer made it very clear that I was missing something, thanks again!